# Derive a formula for $m$, if possible in $2n> \log{(n^{10} m)}^{m}$

Tags: asymptotics, intuition, upper-lower-bounds

We can assume that $m$, and $n$ are reals greater than $1$.  I'm hoping that we can find a (good) bounding function for $m$, meaning a function like:

$$m > f(n)$$

from the inequality

$$2n> (\log{(n^{10} m)})^{m}$$

In other words, I'm trying to find how large $m$ can be for a given $n$.  **Please note that I'm looking for someone to derive the solution.**  In other words, derive the solution that you get.

I've tried using Mathematica to solve this, but it doesn't work.  I've been trying to find a way to collect the $m$ terms together, but so far I've had no luck.  Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Won't $m=2$ do the trick for all $n$ sufficiently large?

Comment: @kimchilover: I'm checking into this.  I'm trying to get $m$ as large as possible for a given $n$.  If $m$ can only be $2$, this would mean I have to find another equation:(

Comment: @kimchilover:  We can make $m=3$ for $n$ sufficiently large, so we can get a better bounds than $m=c$ for some constant.  That's what I'm after; a good asymptotic (lower) bounds on $m$.

Comment: Your question and comments are unclear.  Are you trying to find, for each $n$, what the smallest possible value of $m$ can be?  Or the largest?  Asymptotically, that is.  In the former case, the answer is approximately $1$, independent of $n$.  In the latter, something like $\log n/\log\log n$.  Please clarify.

Comment: @kimchilover: Sorry I was unclear.  I'm trying to find the largest possible value of $m$ for each $n$, or your latter case.  If it is true that $m > \Omega{(\log{n} / \log{ \log{n} } )}$, I would happily accept a proof of this as an answer!

Comment: Edit your question to reflect what you want; maybe people will then think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to solve for $m$ the equation $$2n=\log{\big((n^{10} m)}^{m}\big)=m\left(\log(m)+\log(n^{10})\right)$$ the solution is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$m=\frac{2 n}{W\left(2 n^{11}\right)}$$ and, for large values of $x$, you can use the approximation
$$W(x)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(x)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

So, a first approximation could be
$$m\sim \frac{2 n}{\log \left(n^{11}\right)-\log \left(\log \left(n^{11}\right)\right)}$$

Trying for $n=10^6$, the approximation gives $m=13610$ while the exact solution would be $m=13544$.

**Edit**

Obviously, I misread the equation which is now
$$2n=\left(\log(n^{10} m)\right)^m$$ for which, I am afraid, only numerical methods could work. Since $m$ vary very slowly with $n$, let $\color{red}{n=10^k}$ and use Newton method to get the following table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & m \\
 1 & 0.95568 \\
 2 & 1.38094 \\
 3 & 1.79113 \\
 4 & 2.18554 \\
 5 & 2.56742 \\
 6 & 2.93927 \\
 7 & 3.30285 \\
 8 & 3.65950 \\
 9 & 4.01017 \\
 10 & 4.35565 \\
 11 & 4.69653 \\
 12 & 5.03330 \\
 13 & 5.36637 \\
 14 & 5.69608 \\
 15 & 6.02270 \\
 16 & 6.34650 \\
 17 & 6.66767 \\
 18 & 6.98640 \\
 19 & 7.30287 \\
 20 & 7.61720 \\
 21 & 7.92953 \\
 22 & 8.23998 \\
 23 & 8.54864 \\
 24 & 8.85562 \\
 25 & 9.16099 \\
 26 & 9.46483 \\
 27 & 9.76722 \\
 28 & 10.0682 \\
 29 & 10.3679 \\
 30 & 10.6663
\end{array}
\right)$$

A quick and dirty regression of the totally empirical model
$$m=a+b k^c$$ seems to be very good $(R^2 \sim 1)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval}
   \\
 a & 0.415226 & 0.002492 & \{0.410114,0.420338\} \\
 b & 0.530714 & 0.000956 & \{0.528752,0.532675\} \\
 c & 0.870543 & 0.000484 & \{0.869551,0.871536\} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: I'm very sorry, but the formula is supposed to be $2n> (\log{(n^{10} m)})^{m}$, not $2n> \log{((n^{10} m)^{m}})$. Is it still possible to solve the formula?

Comment: @MattGroff. This is now a very different story. Let me try.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying!  I know it's a tricky formula.  I just haven't been able to collect the $m$ terms together, or to get them in a form where I could use the Lambert $W$ function.  I wish you good luck.

Comment: +1.  This is troubling, though...  Do you think that there's a way to prove that $m$ is at least non-constant?  When I plug in $m = \log{\log{n}}$ into the equation, the limit of (left hand side)/(right hand side) of the equation switches from 0 to infinity.  I really want to prove, somehow, that $m$ is increasing when $n$ increases.  I really could use some sort of asymptotic bounds :(